# socket.io-client v.09 to v1.0 connection issues

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

0 version of socket.io and I cannot find reference to the `connect()` function for the client. The issues I am having is that before I could connect like:

```
var socket = io.connect(
    'localhost',
    {
        port: 3000,
        reconect: true,
        'force new connection': true
    }
```

Now this does not work. My server is not getting the 'connect' event. Looking at the io after trying to connect like so noticed that the port number was not on the managers list and the uri was set to `https://localhost`. If I do `io.connect('http://localhost:3000')` works. Why is this? Does anyone know of any changes made to the connect that was not listed in the migrating  section of the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at the sources of 0.9 and 1.0. I can't find anything called `opts.reconect` (typo?). All I could see was `opts.reconnection`. Also, I'm not sure what your 'force new connection' option is doing.

Anyway, I tested connecting via `var socket = io();`, as well as `var socket = io.connect('localhost', {port:3000});`. Both worked as intended.